# jquery- Closing modal not working on all popups

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set a popup and linked it to 6 products. It is working fine on the first product but not working on others.

```js
<script>

//var modal = document.getElementById("myModal<?php //echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>");

// Get the button that opens the modal
//var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn<?php //echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>");


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("button#pdf").on("click", function(){
        var dataId = jQuery(this).attr("data-pid");
        //alert("The data-id of clicked item is: " + dataId);
        modalpdf = document.getElementById("myPDF" + dataId );
        modalpdf.style.display = "block";
        
                   // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
/*btn.onclick = function() {
  modalpdf.style.display = "block";
}*/

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span1.onclick = function() {
  modalpdf.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modalpdf) {
    modalpdf.style.display = "none";
  }
}

var ct = document.getElementById("closeit");
jQuery(ct).click(function(evt){
    modalpdf.style.display = "none";
});

 
    });
});


 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("button").click(function(evt){
            btn = jQuery(this).attr("id");
            //alert($(this).attr("id"));
            modal = document.getElementById("myModal" + btn );
            //alert(modal);
            modal.style.display = "block";
            
             // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
/*btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}*/

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}


var cv = document.getElementById("closevid");
jQuery(cv).click(function(evt){
    modal.style.display = "none";
});

           
        });
});





</script>
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span id="closevid" class="close">&times;</span>
      <!--h2>Modal Header product no <?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?></h2-->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      
    </div>
    <iframe width="100%" height="450px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php if ( empty(get_field('product_youtube_link')) ) echo 'hmPYDDi_RAo'; else the_field('product_youtube_link');?>">
</iframe>
   
    <!--div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div-->
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: ASAP doesn't apply here

Comment: Hi! Your demo is not working (in snippet you cant use php). Please create minimal working demo

Answer (score 0):

even though snippet is not working I may guess that the issue is here:

```
jQuery("button#pdf").on("click", function()...
```

ID should be unique.

https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

According to the docs it "Selects a single element with the given id attribute.". So if you have multiple items with the same ID (which is an issue) it will pickup the first one.

Instead of querying by ID, you should consider adding class for all your elements (e.g. "pdfitems") and use the following:

```
jQuery("button.pdfitems").on("click", function()
```

https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/